# Ruby: How to put def parameters into a array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Looking at the rspec test I once again need to create a method using define and have it be able to use multiple parameters. I think I need to have those parameters go into a array. I am unsure how to set my parameters so they go into a array and make the parameters infinite so someone could do 
def sum(1,3,4,12,32,18,17,22) or add more or less.

This is my rspec test to make sure it works

```
 describe "sum" do
    it "computes the sum of an empty array" do
    sum([]).should == 0
    end

    it "computes the sum of an array of one number" do
    sum([7]).should == 7
    end

    it "computes the sum of an array of two numbers" do
    sum([7,11]).should == 18
    end

    it "computes the sum of an array of many numbers" do
    sum([1,3,5,7,9]).should == 25
    end
    end
```

So my question is how do I get the define method to input the parameters into a array?

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(*parameters)
  # ...
end
```

will make `parameters=[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` when you invoke `sum(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)`. Notice the asterisk `*` (here called "splat operator").

However, in your RSpec, you're calling `sum([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])`, so it's just a normal array parameter if you continue using that test.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(*params)
  params.length == 0 ? 0 : params.inject(:+)
end

sum(1, 2, 3) => 6
sum(5, 8) => 13
sum(1) => 1
sum() => 0
```

Comment: Doesn't pass the spec for `[]`

Comment: Updated to pass with no parameters.